# when I move an object it permanently moving in 1.0000 increments

Tags: movie-clip-editor

when I move an object it's snapping every 1.0000 increments without me holding anything just move it. 
unlike when you move it smooth.
unlike normal when you open the software

can you please tell me how to fix it

sorry for any spelling mistakes

Comment: it happens in the Node editor as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Blender stack Exchange!

That's because of an option called 'Snap During Transform'. It's a little magnet icon in the toolbar at the bottom of the 3D view (in Blender 2.79b and earlier) or at the top center of the 3D view (Blender 2.80 and later). The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+_<kbd>Tab</kbd>. I find those keys very easy to accidentally bump because of the other shortcuts Blender uses. Disable it and you should be good to go.